# How to convert and compare bytes to Zettabytes and Yottabytes the correct way using PHP?

Tags: php, comparison, byte

I am trying to convert Zettabytes to a Yottabyte based on how many bytes there is in a Zettabyte

When I enter a `$size` value of `1208925819614629174706175` it returns as a Yottabyte `YB` when it should return as a Zettabyte `ZB`.

I have tried using the BC Math functions but I can't get them to work so here I am.

If someone can provide a working example that would help a lot.

Here is my code:

```
$size = 1208925819614629174706175;

if($size < 1208925819614629174706176){
    echo round($size / 1180591620717411303424, 2) .'ZB';
} else if($size >= 1208925819614629174706176){
    echo round($size / 1208925819614629174706176, 2) .'YB';
}
```

I also tried this bc math function

```
bccomp(1208925819614629174706175, 1208925819614629174706176);
```

Which returned `0` should of returned `-1`

Comment: Your $size value there is larger than the biggest integer PHP can handle, even on a 64 bit system. You _need_ to use an extension such as BC Math here.

Comment: You are _still_ using integers as your parameters for the bccomp call there. That is of course pointless, because you can not fix the problem _after_ it occurred - PHP will convert those values to _floats_, and in that step you lose precision. The manual for that function is very clear on that you need to pass the first two parameters as _strings_, is it not? (That is the whole _point_ of the BC extension, that you do _not_ work with actual numbers - which in this case are too large for PHP to handle - but with _strings_ instead.)

Comment: @CBroe even when converted to strings the same problem occurs.

Comment: You need to use BC functions for the other math operations in your code as well, not just in one single place.